# SQL Query - Find Duplicates with a Different Key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data:

```
id  userid  name    group
1   1       A       x
2   1       A       y
3   1       A       z
4   2       B       x
5   2       B       y
6   3       C       y
7   4       D       x
8   5       E       x
9   5       E       z
10  6       F       x
```

I want to find those records that meet all this condition:

**Select all rows where the a userid belongs to a group other than y** *but the userid also belongs to group y*.

The resulting dataset will be as follows:

```
id  userid  name    group
1   1       A       x
3   1       A       z
4   2       B       x
```

If you see, it has resulted in two records for userid a because these are two two records belong to groups other than y but the userid 1 also belongs to group y. Same for userid 2.

I have been breaking my head on how to get this in an SQL statement but not even close to a solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the group column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.group <> t2.group AND t2.group = 'y'
```

I think that would be the fastest query (but please feel free to try the other solutions as well).
Add an index on `user_id` if not already there and maybe play with some other indexes as well (maybe a composite index on `group` and `user_id` can be utilized)

Answer (score 1):

Use `exists`

```
select *
from MyTable a2
where name_group <> 'y'
and exists (select 1 
            from MyTable a2
            where a2.name_group = 'y' 
            and a2.userid = a1.userid)
```

Comment: This has also worked correctly, but I went ahead with the INNER JOIN method suggested by ReneS

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the *users* that meet the condition using aggregation and `having`:

```
select userid
from t
group by userid
having sum( group = 'y' ) > 0 and
       sum( group <> 'y') > 0;
```

I leave it to your to put this into a query to get all the original rows.

Comment: `sum( group = 'y' )` confuses me... Is this the mysql handling of conditional aggregates?

Comment: @JohnHC . . . That i a MySQL shortcut that is basically the same as `sum(case case when group = 'y' then 1 else 0 end)`.  It counts the number of values that are `'y'`.